# ¿Cómo eliminar variables de la URL con jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

**Como eliminar variables de la URL**
*Tengo aquí 2 métodos que obtuve por internet pero no lo he ejecutado aún estoy en eso; estos 2 son de php y jquery*

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#msj-salirReg').click(function(){
        url = document.URL;
        url = String(url.match(/\?+.+/));
        url = url.replace("?", "");

  });
});
```

**Php**

```
    // <?php
    //  if(isset($_GET['existeUsu'])) {
    //      unset($_GET['existeUsu']);
    //  }
    // ?>
```

***Quiero elimnar la Variables : ?existeUsu ***

http://localhost/www/paginaprueba/index.php?existeUsu

quiero que; cuando le des click en la X, el jquery elimine de la url la variable ?existeUsu

Comment: La pregunta no está clara. Sugiero que edites la pregunta **expresando con palabras lo que quieres lograr**. Ejemplo: que cites una url indicando la parte que quieres eliminar de ella.

Comment: Eso lo tendrías que hacer en la configuración de tu servidor con las reglas Rewrite. La verdad que desconozco si se puede hacer con JQuery.

Comment: busco es aprender con las dos formas ya que seria muy interesante

Comment: Igualmente, no entiendo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruab con esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#msj-salirReg').click(function(){
            BorrarHistorial();
      });
    });
    function BorrarHistorial()
    {
      history.pushState({data:true}, 'Titulo', 'index.php');
    }
```

Comment: perfecto amigo lograste remover la variable pero la ventana que fue abierta al pasar la variable no se cerro

Comment: Tendría que ver los elementos de tu modal para darte algunas opciones para cerrar la ventana

Comment: esta listo puse esto dentro del script location.replace("index.php");

Comment: y voy a formular otra pregunta porque veo que me voy acolapsar con puros redirecciones y  supongo que tanto es malo para el rendimiento

Answer (score 0):

Listo amigos ya resolvi aqui les comparto el codigo...

Aqui revisamos  si existe la variable en la url llamada ( existeUsu ); si existe el ejecutara el codigo que sera una ventana, donde incluira un boton llamada ( id="msj-salirReg" ) para cerrar esta misma ventana

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['existeUsu'])) {
?>
    <div id="cont-Msj-existeUsu" >
        <div id="msj-existeUsu" class="centB centBV">
            <div class="msj-simbolo centFRHV">
                <img src="css3/fonts_icons/msj-error.svg">
            </div>
            <div id="msj-salirReg" class="msj-salirReg">X</div>
            <div class="msj-titul">
                Error al Registrar los Datos
            </div>
            <div class="msj-RegExisteUsu">
                <div>Amig@ este Usuario ya existe en nuestro servicio, vuelva a intentarlo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

**Aqui en este Script hacemos Un Evento de Click para cerrar la Ventana**

*Aqui le dare el resumen de los pasos*

*Paso 1: Crear el Evento click a ( id="msj-salirReg" ),para que la accion de cierre de la ventana sea cuando pinchamos a este*

*Paso 2: Asignar la propiedad de display:none asi; 
      $('#cont-Msj-existeUsu').css('display','none'); para desaparecer la ventana*

*Paso 3: Debemos quitar la variable de la Url para que no nos genere problemas, entonces usamos esto:  BorrarHistorial(); y esto : history.pushState({data:true}, 'Titulo', 'index.php'); Asi como se muestra en el codigo*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#msj-salirReg').click(function(){
            $('#cont-Msj-existeUsu').css('display','none');
             BorrarHistorial();
      });
    });
      function BorrarHistorial()
    {
      history.pushState({data:true}, 'Titulo', 'index.php');
    }
</script>
```

**Url con Variable para asignar la ventana**

http://localhost/www/trueque/index.php?existeUsu

**Url sin Variable para que no muestre la ventana al recargar la pagina**

http://localhost/www/trueque/index.php

Comment: Espero que apoyen este codigo